# Beating the dead pony that is the regex question

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question, fun

Much has been discussed about the famous regex question, but I would like to discuss another missing aspect:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/210931?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top
  [image: rocket slide to up]
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/142233?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top 
  [image: hiking to the sky]

Discuss

Comment: I'm sure suggestions of animal cruely could be flagged as offensive.

Comment: Is TheTXI dead?

Comment: Exactly what are these links supposed to be showing? I'm not 100% in the loop on this. Could you enlighten me a little?

Comment: @Thomas: I think he's bothered by the fact that the author of another answer on that question, as well as the asker of the question (both of which started with less than 100 Rep), have both reaped a lot of Rep very quickly due to the attention paid to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Hundreds of rep points!  Two gold badges for Jeff!***  (No, not that Jeff, but the regex OP.)

And yet neither of them can edit my posts, or close yours.  I'm merely jealous.  Still, worthy of discussion.  Three solid days of attention.  Surely it must end soon?

Comment: @Stu, was the 'Surly, it must end soon?' a typo, or a freudian slip?

Comment: No Freudian slip—I'm just a horrible speller.  If the spell check says it is ok, then I am ok.  (Thanks for the heads up.)

Comment: IT HAS ENDED, Jeff made it a wiki.

Answer (score 6):

Are you saying it's a problem that these users got rep so quickly from one answer?  If so, I don't think it's a problem because it's not repeatable (and therefore, almost impossible to intentionally exploit).  A spammer can't just say "I'd like enough rep to wreak havoc on SO.  Let me go provide an answer that will get insanely popular without being CW."  These guys just happened to be in the right place at the right time.

Answer (score 5):

The rep cap works (Jon Skeet clicks downvote in 3... 2... 1...). This question will fizzle out, and the max rep anyone will gain is 200 * length of popularity. Not a big deal, in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that users should be penalized for asking a question that ends up being popular for some reason. We have components in place already on the reputation side to prevent someone from accelerating too fast in the event this happens; however, I do see your concern on the moderation side.

The first user I would be a bit more concerned about granting more powers within the system since they have only had one answer and only been around for four days; however, the second user had been around for three months and has an question and answer recorded. As such, my suggestion would be to put some sort of time based cap in place to prevent someone for getting advanced permissions prior to a certain amount of time going by.

Odds are it takes about a month or so to get a feel for the Stack Overflow community so it would make sense to prevent someone from being able to edit posts (2000 points) prior to that amount of time going by so they get a feel for what sort of edits are acceptable.